# Stacking If Not's seems poor

Tags: vb.net, if-statement, syntax

You can stack these.
Is there a better way?

If Not VAR_watchfolders_NewFile Is Nothing Then

If Not VAR_watchfolders_NewFile = VAR_HoldThisVAR Then

I need to hold back items from a list that gets deleted and prevent them from reoccurring in subsequent lists.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [short-circuiting AndAlso operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx):

```
If VAR_watchfolders_NewFile IsNot Nothing _
    AndAlso VAR_watchfolders_NewFile <> VAR_HoldThisVAR Then

    ... 
End If
```

This ensures that the second condition is only evaluated if the first one evaluates to `True`. You can also replace `Not ... Is Nothing` with `... IsNot Nothing` and `Not ... = ...` with `... <> ...` to improve the readability of your code.

Answer (score 1):

In VB.NET there are 2 operators that you can use to combine multiple conditions:

**And**. If this operator is used, then both of your conditions will be evaluated. So if you use

```
If Not VAR_watchfolders_NewFile Is Nothing And Not VAR_watchfolders_NewFile = VAR_HoldThisVAR Then
```

then this will fail, because second condition will throw an exception.

**AndAlso**. If this operator is used, then right condition will only be evaluated if left condition is true. This means that if you can safely use code

```
If Not VAR_watchfolders_NewFile Is Nothing AndAlso Not VAR_watchfolders_NewFile = VAR_HoldThisVAR Then
```

and if left condition Is false right condition will never be evaluated. For C# users it is identical to using `&&`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can just do this

```
If Not VAR_watchfolders_NewFile is Nothing And Not VAR_watchfolders_NewFile = VAR_HoldThisVAR Then
```

The second expression won't be evaulated if VAR_watchfolders_NewFile is Nothing, so you shouldn't have to worry.

Comment: Not the way you have written it - you need to use the 'AndAlso' operator, not the 'And' operator.